# Can a FH-9000 rear freehub be put on a bicycle with a 7800 Dura-Ace group?

Tags: shimano, cassette, compatibility, freehub

My bike is a Coppi Wing with a 7800 Dura-Ace group. My cassette is a 10-speed Tiagra CS-5700. I have to replace my freehub. Will a Dura-Ace 9000 series freehub fit?

Comment: Seems unlikely. An 11 speed R9000 freehub will be a little longer than a 10 speed.

Comment: @Argenti, seems to make sense, but on https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/duraace-9000/FH-9000.html it looks as if it can support 10 speed and 11 speed.

Comment: Do you want to replace just the freehub body, or the entire hub?

Comment: Not sure....when I go downhill fast w/o pedaling, I get a high-pitched sound. I was told that the freewheel needs to be replaced.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm pretty sure you don't mean freewheel, because those are 5-7 speed systems where the ratcheting mechanism is contained together with the cogs. A freehub body looks like the link at the end. You can't simply mount any freehub body to any hub. We need to know what your rear hub is. https://content.competitivecyclist.com/images/items/900/DTS/DTS000G/BK.jpg

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to replace a 10-speed freehub by a FH-9000 (11-speed) freehub and still be able to use the same CS-5700 (10-speed) cassette. Since a 10-speed cassette is narrower than an 11-speed one, two spacers need to be added between the freehub and the cassette. The following illustration from the [FH-9000 Dealer's Manual](https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/dm/HB0003/DM-HB0003-06-ENG.pdf) on page 5 shows it:

[image]

If you meant to replace only the freehub *body* and not the whole freehub as mentioned by Weiwen Ng in the comment section, you would be very lucky that a Dura-Ace 9000 series freehub body fits on your hub. As an exemple, even the FH-7800 and FH-9000 freehub body, both from the same manufacturer, do not have the same shape and do not attach the same way to the hub.

FH-9000:

[image]

FH-7800:

[image]

[Sheldon Brown](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/k7.html#transplant) has a great page about Shimano freehub body compatibility. Some models are interchangeable between hubs, some are not. The best way forward would just be to order the exact same freehub body that you have if it is the only part that is causing an issue.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have shown that the OP could replace the *hub*. Some of the comments above are discussing that you can’t replace the freehub *body* of a 7800 hub with a 9000-series part. Unfortunately, we don’t know what the OP meant.

Comment: @WeiwenNg you are right. My answer only addresses the original question which was about freehub compatibility. I'll edit my answer to also cover what you pointed out in the comment section about the freehub body compatibility.